# Create DataFrame from df1 and df2 and take empty value from df2 for column value if not exist in df1 column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'call_sign': ['ASD','BSD','CDSF','GFDFD','FHHH'],'frn':['123','124','','656','']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'call_sign': ['ASD','CDSF','BSD','GFDFD','FHHH'],'frn':['1234','','124','','765']})
```

need to get a new df like

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'call_sign': ['ASD','BSD','CDSF','GFDFD','FHHH'],'frn':['123','','124','656','765']})
```

I need to take frn from df2 if it's missing in df1 and create a new df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace empty strings to missing values and use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), because need ordering like `df2.call_sign` add [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = (df1.set_index('call_sign').replace('', np.nan)
          .fillna(df2.set_index('call_sign').replace('', np.nan))
         .reindex(df2['call_sign']).reset_index())
print(df)
  call_sign  frn
0       ASD  123
1      CDSF  NaN
2       BSD  124
3     GFDFD  656
4      FHHH  765
```

Comment: But had an issue. cant set index the callsign order can be different

Comment: @abhikrishnan - Can you change data for see issue?

Comment: df1 = pd.DataFrame({'call_sign': ['ASD','BSD','CDSF','GFDFD','FHHH'],'frn':['123','124','','656','']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'call_sign': ['ASD','CDSF','BSD','GFDFD','FHHH'],'frn':['1234','','124','','765']})

Comment: en eg: then i will get valu 124 in CDSF but actually its need to be '' or nan

Comment: NOw i edited my question DF can you please check

Comment: @abhikrishnan - So need replace df1 by df2 and then change order by df2?

Comment: sorry didn't get you. as am new to data science

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update `df2` you can use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
# is frn empty string?
m = df2['frn'].eq('')
# update those rows from the value in df1
df2.loc[m, 'frn'] = df2.loc[m, 'call_sign'].map(df1.set_index('call_sign')['frn'])
```

Updated `df2`:

```
  call_sign   frn
0       ASD  1234
1      CDSF      
2       BSD   124
3     GFDFD   656
4      FHHH   765
```

Answer (score 0):

```
temp = df1.merge(df2,how='left',on='call_sign')
df1['frn']=temp.frn_x.where(temp.frn_x!='',temp.frn_y)
```

```
    call_sign   frn
0   ASD         123
1   BSD     
2   CDSF        124
3   GFDFD       656
4   FHHH        765
```